# Calculate the limit of the number sequence $\sqrt{2n-8}^{\frac{1}{n-4}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Calculate the limit of the number sequence $\sqrt{2n-8}^{\frac{1}{n-4}}$

$\sqrt{2n-8}^{\frac{1}{n-4}}=((2n-8)^\frac 1 2)^\frac{1}{n-4}=(2n-8)^\frac{1}{2n-8}\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} (2n-8)^\frac{1}{2n-8}=(2n-8)^0\to 1$ Is that enough to prove, that the limit is $1$? Did I forgot any steps that are necessary?

We haven't discussed L'Hopital's rule yet. It would be helpful if you could give me hints without the Rule of L'Hopital

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} (2n-8)^\frac{1}{2n-8}=\infty^0$, so it is possible not be $1$, but this case is $1$

Comment: Use a substitution to show you have $\lim_{n-\rightarrow\infty} n^{1/n}$. This should be familiar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following along from your answer, we are trying to compute $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (2n-8)^{\frac{1}{2n-8}}$, writing $m = 2n-8$, and noting that $m = \phi(n) = 2n-8$ is in fact a bijection, it is clear $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (2n-8)^{\frac{1}{2n-8}} = lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} ,m^{\frac{1}{m}}$ which is a standard limit you can choose to evaluate however you like. To show it exists, it is enough to notice $m^{\frac{1}{m}} = \exp(\frac{1}{m}Log(m))$, and $\frac{1}{m}Log(m) \rightarrow 0$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$, so your limit is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take logarithm. Use L'Hopital's Rule to show that $\frac 1{ 2n-8} \ln (2n-8) \to 0$. So the answer is $1$.

To show that $\frac {\ln x} x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ without the use of LHopital's Rule you can use the following argument:

$\ln (1+x) \leq x$ for all $x \geq 0$. Now  $\frac {\ln x} x  = 2 \frac {\ln \sqrt x} x \leq 2\frac {\sqrt x -1} x=\frac 2 {\sqrt x}-\frac 2 x \to 0$.

Comment: We haven't discussed L'Hopital's rule yet. I will edit my post.

Comment: @Doesbaddel I have given another proof using the fact that $\ln (1+x) \leq x$. [This inequality can be proved by noting that $\ln (1+x) -x$ is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ and has the value $0$ at $0$.

Comment: Thank you! ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed L'Hopital then consider $(\sqrt{2n - 8})^{1/(n-4)}$.  It is easy to combine the square root with the existing exponent to see that this is $(2n-8)^{\frac 1{(2n-8)}}$. Now, look at $\lim_{t \to \infty} t^{\frac 1t}$ along the positive integers. Note that 
by Bernoulli's inequality,we have $e^x \leq 1+ x$ for all real $x$, so using this gives :
$$
1 \leq t^{\frac 1t} = e ^{\ln t/t} \leq 1+ \ln t/t
$$

for every $t \geq 1$ a positive integer. Since $\ln t/t \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, we see that by the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{t \to \infty} t^{\frac 1t} = 1$. Now, the sequence $(2n-8)^{\frac 1{2n-8}}$ is a subsequence of this sequence, so it must have the same limit i.e. $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use that

$$\sqrt{2n-8}^{\frac{1}{n-4}}=\left(2n-8\right)^{\frac{1}{2n-8}}=e^{\frac{\log (2n-8)}{2n-8}} \to 1$$

indeed

$$\frac{\log (2n-8)}{2n-8} \to 0$$

to prove that let consider as $x\to \infty$

$$\frac{\log x}{x} \to 0$$

indeed by $x=e^y$

$$\frac{\log x}{x} =\frac{\log e^y}{e^y}=\frac{y}{e^y}\to 0$$

since eventually $e^y\ge y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be reduced to the evaluation of $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1/n}$. Here is one way to evaluate it. If $n>3$ then you can show that the sequence $n^{1/n}$ is decreasing and clearly it is bounded below by $1$. Therefore it tends to a limit $L$ with $L\geq 1$.

Next we derive a contradiction by assuming $L>1$ and thereby establish that the desired limit is $1$. If $n^{1/n}\to L>1$ then there is some number $k$ with $1<k<L$ and a positive integer $m$ such that $n^{1/n}>k$ for all $n>m$. This means that $n>k^n$ for all $n>m$.

Let $k=1+h$ with $h>0$ and then $$k^n=(1+h) ^n>\frac{n(n-1)}{2}h^2$$ if $n>2$. And $n>k^n$ therefore implies that $$n>\frac{n(n-1)}{2}h^2$$ for all $n>\max(2,m)$. This means that $n-1<2/h^2$ and this is clearly false as LHS of the inequality tends to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty $ whereas the RHS remains fixed.